# What attributes are allowed on custom django admin field methods?

Tags: django, django-admin

I've noticed in some Django project that uses Django admin methods on model-admin that look like this:

```
def some_field(self, obj):
    return calculate_something(obj)
some_field.short_description = "Some description"
```

And then it's used in field-set as normal field. It gets somehow magically recognized by name.

Where can I find documentation about the `short_description` and what other things I can set?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: You can set any attribute on a function. Just like objects.

Comment: @IainShelvington
These are attributes set directly on class. I meant the ones set on method like shown in the example.
@WillemVanOnsem
Yes, I know. But some attributes seem to have special meaning.

My guess is that attributes like `boolean` or `short_description` are used internally by some Django admin template, and something like [display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display) should be used instead. But I'm not sure.

Comment: The doc linked in post above even says it's equivalent, so I'm probably right, it just doesn't name all the possible attributes explicitely, but at least I know there is some equivalence and there (probably) aren't many "secret" attributes I don't know about.

Comment: @user224348 The docs for [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) detail the attributes and their purpose in slightly more depth